# Is there a one byte "trap" instruction in x86?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm looking for a *trap* instruction that raises a hardware exception so that the program will stop abruptly and the debugger can show where this point is.

`ud2` seems to do the job, but is there a one byte option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `int3` instruction with opcode `cc`.  When debugging the program, this instruction causes a breakpoint.  When not debugging the program, it usually causes some sort of trap.

Comment: The debugger I'm using (`gdb` on Windows) does catch this, but unfortunately the program just exits normally when executing normally. For `ud2`, the system handles it and prints an error message. I have no idea about other systems.

Comment: @xiver77 Unfortunate.  You could also try execute a privileged instruction like `hlt` or `cli`.

Comment: @xiver77: x86-64 has a few one-byte illegal instructions (at least for now, until the opcodes for `aaa`, `push ds` and so on get repurposed).  Check http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html for the "invalid" entries.  In 32-bit mode, all the 1-byte opcodes are used, though.